# Insert SQL Date as ISODate in mongodb using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I am reading timestamps from MSSQL database like `2013-02-15 13:02:16.000` or `2013-02-15 13:02:16`, how can I insert them as ISODate in MangoDB.

I have tried the following but it does not work

```
doc.put(col, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(value));
```

The results I get when I query the collection is represented as a string instead

```
 "DateCreated" : "2012-09-11 19:06:45.0",
 "DateModified" : "2012-09-11 19:06:45.0",
```

and I am expecting something like

```
"DateCreated" : ISODate("2012-09-11T19:06:45.xxZ)",
"DateModified" : ISODate("2012-09-11 19:06:45.0"),
```

Comment: Have you tried updating with `new Date(your_date_var)`?

Comment: @titi23, yes I have tried that but Date(val) is deprecated. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I thought you are using javascript, so I have added the comment. `new Date()` is from javascript. I don't know how to do it using Java.

Answer (score 3):

Please try with below code. This should insert date as ISODate("2013-02-15T13:02:16.100Z") in Mongo DB collection.

```
    LocalDateTime ld = LocalDateTime.parse("2013-02-15 13:02:16.100",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));        
    Date date = Date.from(ld.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());   
    doc.put(col, date);
```

If ZoneId needs to be considered. Please refer the below code and change the zone id accordingly.

```
Date date = Date.from(ld.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html

```
Date date = Date.from(ld.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Darwin")).toInstant());

                America/Caracas     -04:30
               America/St_Johns     -02:30
                  Asia/Calcutta     +05:30
                   Asia/Colombo     +05:30
                     Asia/Kabul     +04:30
                 Asia/Kathmandu     +05:45
                  Asia/Katmandu     +05:45
                   Asia/Kolkata     +05:30
                   Asia/Rangoon     +06:30
                    Asia/Tehran     +04:30
             Australia/Adelaide     +09:30
          Australia/Broken_Hill     +09:30
               Australia/Darwin     +09:30
                Australia/Eucla     +08:45
                  Australia/LHI     +10:30
            Australia/Lord_Howe     +10:30
                Australia/North     +09:30
                Australia/South     +09:30
           Australia/Yancowinna     +09:30
            Canada/Newfoundland     -02:30
                   Indian/Cocos     +06:30
                           Iran     +04:30
                        NZ-CHAT     +12:45
                Pacific/Chatham     +12:45
              Pacific/Marquesas     -09:30
                Pacific/Norfolk     +11:30
```

Comment: Incorrect Answer. Will not generate the specified value. Applying the JVM’s current default time zone is inappropriate here. Doing so charge the meaning of the data. Only apply a specific time zone, and do do only when you know the intended time zone of the context where that data came from. The JVM’s current default time zone could be *anything*, and worse, it can change at any moment *during* runtime.

Comment: The answer was provided to give an idea to store the date as ISODate in MongoDB as it is the original question. If the zoneId needs to be considered, then the below code can be used accordingly based on the requirement.
Date date = Date.from(ld.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());

List of Zone Id link.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html